# Give a specific team an item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a minigame where when someone presses a button they join a team and teleport somewhere. I then want a chain command block to give them a book, but I want a specific team to get that item. Whenever I try doing it, it gives it to the wrong person.

I tried to use this command:

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {author:Narrator,title:WereWolf,pages:["\".The goal of the werewolves is to decide together on one villager to secretly kill off during the night, while posing as villagers during the day so they're not killed off themselves."]}
```

I want to give the book to a certain team, but whenever I do like @a[team=Red] It doesn't work

Comment: Hi Allimant, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Or: how did you try doing it?

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward, so I assume you're doing something different. Please specify what you tried.

Comment: I used this command, /give @p written_book 1 0 {author:Narrator,title:WereWolf,pages:["\". The goal of the werewolves is to decide together on one villager to secretly kill off during the night, while posing as villagers during the day so they're not killed off themselves."]}

Comment: I want it to give it to a certain, team but whenever I do like @a[team=Red] It doesn't work

Comment: Does teleporting the player work propperly? What command do you use for that? Have you tried giving the player the book before they teleport?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/give @p [r=40,x=X coordinate,y=y coordinate,z=z coordinate]`, followed by the item. Make sure to set `x`, `y`, and `z` to the middle of where each team spawns, assuming it’s a room. If not, do `[r=5]`.